# pytest scope function not creating 2 instances of browser

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-django, xdist

I am trying to run 2 tests in parallel using `xdist` so before that I tried to make each test independent.

This is where I'm setting up browser.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def moduleSetup(request):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    def fin():
        driver.close()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return driver
```

And here are 2 tests I'm running

```
def test_1(moduleSetup):
    print moduleSetup
    moduleSetup.get('http://www.foo.com')
    time.sleep(5)

def test_2(moduleSetup):
    print moduleSetup
    moduleSetup.get('www.bar.com')
    time.sleep(5)
```

But when I run tests I get

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="5aae6a2d-6940-1c47-8c21-8403f84a2acb")>
...
.<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="5aae6a2d-6940-1c47-8c21-8403f84a2acb")>
```

As you can see it is using same browser instance. I thought if I set `scope` as `function` it will create 2 browser instances?

If above works end goal is run tests in parallel like maybe using `py.test -d --tx 3*popen//python=python2.7 test.py -s`? So it will launch 2 browsers simultaneously.

Comment: I used the exact code and it works for me what version of selenium are you using?

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana Mine is selenium==2.48.0 and Firefox browser

Comment: I have a 2.53 version (latest selenium and it works for me)<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="afe30f4c-72ed-4a3a-a7fd-5ef3f75c9e77")>
.<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="1c957d1b-022e-4dfc-937e-6ceca5894854")>

Comment: Just to rule out it is not a problem with pytest can you try some other object (other than driver). Then you can upgrade your selenium

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana not sure what was I doing wrong but I created new project and I see 2 different driver objects. But when I run in parallel using `py.test -d --tx 3*popen//python=python2.7 test.py -s` it still run serially one after other, aren't both suppose to run at same time?